# how to select more than one element with almost the same xpath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

i have some elements with the following xpath format:

//*[@id="dashboardRoot"]/span/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[i]

where i = 1,2,3,4,....etc

How to select an element every time in a loop?

i tried this way:

```
for i in range(5):
    
    try:
        
        xpath = '//*[@id="dashboardRoot"]/span/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr["i+1"]'

        select_card = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

but it works with the first element every time and don't move tho the next one.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to place the `i` value in the string, you must put it in the string format as below :

```
xpath = f'//*[@id="dashboardRoot"]/span/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[{i+1}]'
```

or

```
xpath = '//*[@id="dashboardRoot"]/span/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[{}]'.format(i+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of find element,use find elements.your code should be this:

```
xpath = '//*[@id="dashboardRoot"]/span/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr'
elements= browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
for element in elements:
    element.click()
```